# How can I change the order of traces in horizontal Plotly bar chart?

Tags: r, plotly, bar-chart, r-plotly

When I add a trace to a horizontal bar chart in R Plotly the additional trace is placed above the first trace, but in the legend it is vice versa. How can I place the additional trece under the first one as in the legend?

And/or how can I change the order in the legend?

[image: bar chart]

```
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
df <- mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarise_at(c('qsec','mpg'), funs(mean))


figh <- plot_ly(df, y = ~ cyl, x = ~ qsec, type = 'bar', orientation = 'h'
               ,marker = list(color = 'rgb(80, 160, 200)')
)
figh <- figh %>% add_trace(x = ~ mpg
                         ,marker = list(color = 'rgb(220, 80, 80)')
)
figh
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the order in the legend, you can change `traceorder` in `legend` using `layout`.

`traceorder`...

> Determines the order at which the legend items are displayed. If
> "normal", the items are displayed top-to-bottom in the same order as
> the input data. If "reversed", the items are displayed in the opposite
> order as "normal".

https://plotly.com/r/reference/layout/#layout-legend-traceorder

```
layout(figh, legend = list(traceorder = "reversed"))
```